# Automated debugging tools

Tags: debugging, automation, automated-tests

I have recently discovered the amazing world of automated debugging, where your tool try to automatically isolate the part of the code that causes a bug. Since then, I have found some tools, like these:

- [delta debugging](https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/dd/) (implementation in [DD.py](https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/dd/DD.py)) using scientific methodology applied to debugging.
- static and dynamic [program slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_slicing) extracting a subprogram trace highlighting the variables you want to observe.
- [git-bisect](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) using [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_(software_engineering)) applied to code history and mixed with delta debugging to quickly find what change caused the bug.

I'm interested into finding more **algorithms** for automated debugging, which can automate some part (or all?) of the debugging process and where a **pratical working implementation exists**, particularly:

- approaches such as delta debugging (which can precisely pinpoint where and why a bug happens in the code by using a systematic/automated approach).
- is there a software that can automatically generate a [minimal program that reproduces a bug](http://sscce.org/) from a full program?

NB: some tools I cited are mainly geared towards Python but I am looking for automated debugging tools on any language, what is interesting me is the approach and algorithms, not the specific implementation, but I require an implementation (even a proof of concept) because I would like algorithms which have already been practically applied to real problems (ie, they work, that's just not computer science philosophy).

Clarification: I'm not looking for automated testing tools (which automatically test to find a new bug), but automated debugging approaches where you have a specific bug you want to find the origin in your code.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157903/are-their-semi-automatic-tools-to-help-produce-minimal-test-cases-similar-to-gi?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035891/what-is-the-name-for-this-bug-finding-technique-and-do-programs-exist-to-automat?rq=1

Comment: [This post](https://pingcap.com/blog/squashed-bugs-served-hot-and-fresh-with-failure-rate-heatmaps/) presents an interesting and **practical implementation** of automated debugging - automatically finding bugs based on fuzzing, statistical debugging, and visualization technique. FYI.

Answer (score 5):

I have found a few softwares that can generate a minimal program that reproduces a bug:

- [DD.py](https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/dd/DD.py) has in fact two functions: dd() to find the minimal change that introduced a bug, and ddmin() which finds the minimal configuration (ie, minimal test case).
- [Delta](http://delta.tigris.org/), a program specifically tailored for that purpose.

I also found a course on Udacity called [Software Debugging](https://www.udacity.com/course/software-debugging--cs259) which is presented by [Andreas Zeller, the original author of delta debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_Debugging).

Side note: these are also somewhat related tools (although they are mainly unit testing tools, they can be used in combination with automated debugging so it's kind of related):

- [coveralls](https://coveralls.io/)
- [coverage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage/4.0a6)
- [automated unit test generator Pythoscope](http://pythoscope.org/)

I am still looking for alternative approaches to automated debugging.